# Import code from text VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, text

Is it event possible to import text as code, then add it in a sub in vb.net?
If I have a .txt file filled with code can I import it programatically (by a button)?

What I need is to make vb.net to accept that script (txt file), and use it to declare variables and make functions/subs - that's all I need to.

Comment: You might be able to do it using Eval() but I don't think so.

Comment: It is possible to dynamically compile an assembly using the CodeDom stuff.  It's somewhat easy to do, for those who have a decent grasp of .NET, but it should always be done sparingly.  Typically there is a better way of doing what you need to do.  Why do you think you need to do it?

Comment: For an example of what I mean by using CodeDom, take a look at my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10948013/1359668.  It's in C#, but it should give you the idea of what I'm talking about.

Comment: I would my program to read the text file then add that text as a code into a sub. I don't think this could be that hard.
Another idea - make the program "download" the code from the internet, but I still don't know how to add it to a sub

Comment: You can't add it to a sub that's already defined in your current assembly, but you can create the sub with the code in a new dynamically-generated assembly--a class library, and then call *that* from your current assembly.  Does that interest you?  If so, I could work up an example in VB.NET and post it as an answer.

Comment: Everything is good. I only need to use the code to declare variables and execute them at a specified time. No matter if the code is in another sub, but the variables must be global. If you could make me a code like that I'll be extremely gratefull

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you are trying to do.  Could you explain it further?

Comment: As @StevenDoggart pointed out, it would be better if you described the need for such behavior. There are many issues with this approach, and there is most likely a better way to do what you want. But we cannot help you further without more details from you.

Comment: Please don't put all the details in a comment.  Please edit your original question to provide the details.  It will be much easier for everyone to read that way.

Comment: I updated it. It's very hard to explain (because I explained it THREE times)

Comment: We're trying to help.  No need to get snippy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this kind of thing using the CodeDom objects.  The CodeDom objects allow you to dynamically generate assemblies at run-time.  For instance, if you make an interface

```
Public Interface IScript
    Property Variable1 As String
    Sub DoWork()
End Interface
```

Then, you create a method, like this:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.CodeDom.Compiler

' ...

Public Function GenerateScript(code As String) As IScript
    Using provider As New VBCodeProvider()
        Dim parameters As New CompilerParameters()
        parameters.GenerateInMemory = True
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
        Dim interfaceNamespace As String = GetType(IScript).Namespace
        Dim codeArray() As String = New String() {"Imports " & interfaceNamespace & Environment.NewLine & code}
        Dim results As CompilerResults = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, codeArray)
        If results.Errors.HasErrors Then
            Throw New Exception("Failed to compile script")
        Else
            Return CType(results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("Script"), IScript)
        End If
    End Using
End Function
```

Now, you can call it like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim builder As New StringBuilder()
    builder.AppendLine("Public Class Script")
    builder.AppendLine("    Implements IScript")
    builder.AppendLine("    Public Property Variable1 As String Implements IScript.Variable1")
    builder.AppendLine("    Public Sub DoWork() Implements IScript.DoWork")
    builder.AppendLine("        Variable1 = ""Hello World""")
    builder.AppendLine("    End Sub")
    builder.AppendLine("End Class")
    Dim script As IScript = GenerateScript(builder.ToString())
    script.DoWork()
    MessageBox.Show(script.Variable1) ' Displays "Hello World"
End Sub
```

Obviously, instead of building the code in a string builder, you could load it out of a text file, like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim script As IScript = GenerateScript(File.ReadAllText("C:\script.txt")
    script.DoWork()
    MessageBox.Show(script.Variable1) ' Displays "Hello World"
End Sub
```

Comment: when I use script.DoWork() what happens exactly?  P.S: Sorry for being "snippy", I was a bit nervous so...hope you don't care about that and reply to my question :)

Comment: No hard feelings, I know how it goes :)  Anyway, when you call `script.DoWork`, it calls the `Script.DoWork` method that is defined in the string builder.  In my example, all it does is set the value of the `Variable1` property to `"Hello World"`.  But it could do anything you want--that's the beauty of it being a script :)

Comment: So it executes the code right? But how do I declare a variable (or a global one)? It's optional, but it's for my general knowledge

Comment: Yes, calling the `DoWork` method executes the code in the `DoWork` method, just as if it was defined locally in your own pre-compiled assembly.  I just showed that `IScript` interface as an example.  You could have as many methods and properties defined in that interface as you need.  The `Variable1` property was my attempt at demonstrating how to declare a *variable*, as you mentioned, with a script.