# How to read VB formatted code from a text file?

Tags: vb.net

I writing a pair of programs in visual basics that will consist of a client and receiver. The client is completed making an output text file similar to below.

```
Dim FileName As String = "Text.txt"
Dim message As String
Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter

'lblmessage.text says "Call MsgBox("Hello!", 0, "Version Beta 0.3")"

lblmessage.text = message
Dim Drive As String = "C:\hello world\" & FileName
file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(Drive, True)
file.WriteLine(message)
file.Close()
```

A sister program that is designed to be a reader will read the generated file.
The program will then take the text located in the selected file and use it as code in the readers programming.

Best example I can show...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim fileReader As String
    fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\hello world\Text.txt")

    fileReader

End Sub
```

where "fileReader" is suppose to run the generated code from the previous program and use it as code it the Reader.

The point of this program is to create help tickets in the client and have a tool for reviewing these ticket in the same way they were submitted through the second app.

Comment: You don't seem to be asking a specific question, or stating what problem you're having.

Comment: Well, it was specific enough for Joshua K to answer. Do you know how to lock a question or close a discussion.

Comment: @MikeMaz if you want that a person read your comment, you have to type `@NAME` in your comment. ElmerCat won't read your comment, because he/she will never get a notification about your comment. Just as a hint ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vba and vb.net is different. I'm not sure in which language your doing your stuff.

- vba: use the `ScriptControl.Eval` command to execute a bunch of commands.
- vb.net: it's a bit more code. you can use `VBCodeProvider` Class. s this SO Question: [Load VB.net code from .txt file and execute it on fly using System.CodeDom.Compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21379926/load-vb-net-code-from-txt-file-and-execute-it-on-fly-using-system-codedom-compi)

**UPDATE**

I found a perfekt resource if you are interested in how to do it right and how it works in the background: http://www.codemag.com/article/0211081