# Execute the code stored as a String in VB.NET

Tags: string, vb.net, parsing, runtime

I wonder about how I can store a part of code in a string field of an object and convert it at run-time in executable code.

Let's say I have my class:

```
Public Class Car

Public m_IDCar As String
Public m_Brand As String
Public m_Description As String
Public m_Condition As String ' => here I need to store an If, or an If condition as a String, that will be executed at run-time.

End Class
```

Then the code that happens when `CommandButton1.Click()`:

```
Dim  carList As List(Of Car)
Dim parameter as String

' here I create carList with data from a database, so for each car In the database I create its relative object, with its .m_IDCar, .m_Brand, .m_Description and .m_Condition, and add it to carList

parameter = TextBox1.Text ' => given in input by the user

For each car As Car in carList
    If (car.m_Condition = True) then  ' => here there must be something to do cause, as things are now, in car.m_Condition is stored a String, but I need to parse it in code that returns a boolean value and, if this value would be True, the code will enter in the If statement.
        'do something
     End If
Next
```

Example of `car.m_Condition` could be:

```
car.m_Condition = "(car.m_Name=""BMW"" AND car.m_Description.Contains(parameter)) OR car.m_Brand=""AUDI"""
```

I need some tips on how to implement this approach, if someone would help me.

TY!

EDIT:
Thanks David, I have seen that question and seems a lot similar. I've seen that the user asked how store the entire If in a string:

```
Dim code As String = "IIf(1 = 2, True, False)"
```

(the users that asked that question used IIf)

The best way for me would be to store the condition to evaluate in a string and, maybe, the value to with compare the result in another one. So, for example:

```
Dim condition As String = "(car.m_Name=""BMW"" AND car.m_Description.Contains(parameter)) OR car.m_Brand=""AUDI"""
Dim valueToCompareWith as String = "True"
```

and the following If

```
If (car.m_Name=""BMW"" AND car.m_Description.Contains(parameter)) OR car.m_Brand=""AUDI"" = True) Then
'do something
End If
```

will become:

```
If (condition = valueToCompareWith) Then '(conceptually, because in this form it's simply a String comparison that returns always False)
'do something
End If
```

EDIT2:

Thanks Plutonix, I've read about your hint on Getters and Setters, I've not specified it, but the context I'm working on is a lot more complex then this. I've made a very simple example just for focus the problem, but I'm working with a good amount of objects, with various fields to compare and for every comparison there are different conditions in the If, with different logics and different types of data to compare.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic code execution: String -> Runtime code VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200047/dynamic-code-execution-string-runtime-code-vb-net)

Comment: Change those fields to properties and embed all the code and logic you want in the Getters and Setters.  No need to go the route of converting strngs to executable code. Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Hi Plutonix and thanks for hint. I'm going to study in deep what you and David have suggested to me. I only need to ask to you what I've done wrong in asking my question, because I've already read the How To Ask session, I was convinced to have made a correct question. Please consider that I am a newbie in programming and that english is not my first lang, so I'm sorry for my mistakes.