# Is there any method programatically edit/add code in Vb.NET?

Tags: vb.net

in VBA, it support us to add/edit code programatically in a module through VBE.

**Do we have any similar method in VB.NET** or any other language ?

if we're able to let the program write function by itself then it'll be very interesting to see.

For example:

1. I have module A, it have function test() inside
   now I have code-string of function Hello() I want to add to module A
   I read some post those are on-fly complier.
2. I have Class School, which have method AddStudent()
   Now I saw a usefull method AddTeacher() somewhere in the internet.
   I don't wanna open class School then copy/paste or type those code of method AddTeacher().

   Is there anyway I can add that method into Class School like this:

   ```
   Dim Harvard as new School
   Harvard.addMethod "string code of method AddTeacher()"
   Harvard.addTeacher "Sarah", "Math"
   ```

More detail:
I have class School

```
Public Class School
  Public Function AddMethod(strCode$)
  'magic method
  End Function

  Public Function AddStudent(ClassName$, Number%)
  End Function
End Class
```

after I run the 2nd example (I don't know exactly way)
class School mutate into this:

```
Public Class School
  Public Function AddMethod(strCode$)
  'magic method
  End Function

  Public Function AddStudent(ClassName$, Number%)
  End Function

  Public Function AddTeacher(Name$, subject$)
  End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Question is unclear, but you probably should look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709263/import-code-from-text-vb-net/14711110#14711110

Comment: I've read that, it similar to on fly complie right ? btw, that may be a work around, do we have any direct method ? I mean for example I have module A with function Test() inside it, now I want to add function Helloworld() into module A without typing it line by line in Visual studio, how to do that ? :D

Comment: Check out Extension methods.

Comment: @Mary: "Extension methods enable developers to add custom functionality to data types that are already defined without creating a new derived type". Extension is good method, it look like a temporary interface for instances. but we have to type or copy/paste  code for that new extension...

Comment: @Mary That alone won't help, extension methods are just syntactic sugar for pretending a method belongs to a different class.

Comment: If you don't want to open a class to add a method, then use extension methods.

Comment: @Mary: nah, well, don't open a class and don't type anything too. you can see my detail above :D this look like a challenge in codefight.com haha

Comment: @Mary the way I read it, I don't think that's what the OP is looking for, sounds like they are looking to (at runtime) compile a new method and add it to the class. "if we're able to let the program write function by itself then it'll be very interesting to see.", "I want to add to module A I read some post those are on-fly complier."

Comment: Fine, it was just a one line comment!

Comment: @Mary: you did well, need more active member like you <3

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this:

- [Reflect.Emit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [CodeDOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/using-the-codedom)
- [Roslyn](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/compiling-c-sharp-code-into-memory-and-executing-it-with-roslyn)

There are probably others. However, you won't find anything as simple as the `Eval()` method you may have seen in some other platforms, and *this omission is intentional.* .Net is a full-featured platform, intended to be used in a wide variety of places. An Eval()-like mechanism has the ability to do anything you could possibly write a .Net program to do... including some things that aren't very nice.

Comment: so you mean python or other language can do what I ask for ? 
I start to research on AI, I have to ask before build a custom platform for this. it just a hobby btw ^^